# how to stop this while loop in python

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop

I want to generate a sequence of numbers starting from 2 and calculating each successive number in the sequence as the square of the previous number minus one.

```
x = 2
while 0 <= x <= 10:
    x ** 2 - 1

print(x)
```

note: Iam interested in finding the first number in the sequence greater than ten or less than zero

but the loop keeps repeating with the same answer of 3. how do i stop it?

Comment: `x` never changes, what do you expect?

Comment: Put the print inside the while and follow the answer below

Comment: Use `python -m pdb <your-script>` to debug your script and see why it won't work, when you stepwise run through your endless loop.

Answer (score 4):

you're not affecting x

```
x = 2
while 0 <= x <= 10:
    x = x ** 2 - 1

print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to update the value of x so that the `while` statement will eventually be false.

```
x = 2
while 0 <= x <= 10:
    x = x ** 2 - 1
print(x)
```